# Who introduced the notation $\lesssim$?

Tags: notation, math-history

Who in history introduced the notation $X\lesssim Y$ for meaning $X\leq CY$ for some constant $C$? I've seen this notation in modern literature in PDE a lot. (See for instance the notation section of  *Nonlinear dispersive equations: local and global analysis* by Terence Tao.) But it seldom appears in undergraduate textbooks.

Comment: I never saw this notation with this meaning (but with a different one). But then I do not do PDE. Still can you give a specific example where it is used with the meaning you claim (and this is apparent).

Comment: Never actually saw it, but I could rather imagine it has similar meaning to $X \approx Y$; just transferred to relative symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terry Tao says the following in his [lecture notes on real analysis](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/):

> ... we use ${X \lesssim_p Y}$ as shorthand for the inequality ${X \leq C_p Y}$ for some constant ${C_p}$ depending only on ${p}$ (it can be a different constant at each use of the ${\lesssim_p}$ notation). [Note: in analytic number theory, it is more customary to use ${\ll_p}$ instead of ${\lesssim_p}$, following *Vinogradov*. However, in analysis ${\ll}$ is sometimes used instead to denote “much smaller than”, e.g. ${X \ll Y}$ denotes the assertion ${X \leq cY}$ for some sufficiently small constant ${c}$.]

See also [this set of notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247a.1.06f/notes1.pdf) on harmonic analysis regarding the Vinogradov notation.