# An elementary inequality involving exponentials

Tags: inequality

In a paper that I'm reading, the authors use the following "elementary inequality" to further derive other inequalities. For $ \sigma > 0, \gamma \in [0,1], x \geq y$, and $\langle \cdot \rangle$ is the [Japanese bracket](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12887/what-is-the-origin-of-the-japanese-bracket), i.e. $\ \langle x \rangle = \sqrt{1+x^2}$, we have $$ e^{\langle x \rangle^{\gamma}} \langle x \rangle^{\sigma} - e^{\langle y \rangle^{\gamma}} \langle y \rangle^{\sigma} \lesssim \frac{|x-y|}{\langle x\rangle^{1 - \gamma} + \langle y \rangle^{1-\gamma}} \langle x \rangle^{\sigma} e^{\langle x \rangle^{\gamma}}$$

I am unable to prove this inequality. I have tried using the mean-value theorem or convexity arguments but it doesn not help with having both $\langle x \rangle^{1-\gamma}$ and $\langle y \rangle^{1- \gamma}$ in the denominator. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the paper you’re reading?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I've edited the post now. It was supposed to mean the Japanese bracket, but I messed up the MathJax syntax.

Comment: @Clayton Landau damping for analytic and Gevrey data by Grenier et. al.

Comment: The denominator has $\langle x\rangle$ twice and powers of $1-\gamma$, $\gamma$. That reduces to $\langle x\rangle^{1-\gamma}\langle x\rangle^\gamma=\langle x\rangle$. Is that a typo?

Comment: @jwhite yup, sorry about that. Corrected right now.

Comment: What does  $\lesssim$ mean?

Comment: If $x\ge y$, why the absolute value in $|x-y|$?

Comment: @JairTaylor: [Less than a constant multiple of](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793395/who-introduced-the-notation-lesssim).

Comment: @jjagmath I agree. The absolute value is not necessary here, but I copied the inequality as it appeared in the paper.